# Copy files inside a pod from helm chart taken directly from helm repository

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-templating

I have taken a helm chart : `grafana` directly from helm-repository. Now i need to copy a file inside grafana-pod at a specific location. I can do it by :

```
kubectl cp <file-to-be-copied> <pod-name>:<target-location-inside-pod>
```

But i need to automate it, so i was looking for `volumeMount` but i couldn't find any `deployment.yaml/templates` to add it into.
Let me know if there's any provision/method to automate this operation via kubernetes or grafana.

Comment: Usually Charts expose a extraVolumeMounts in their values which can help you doing exactly what you want. Maybe even better, if the file is just a configuration file, would be to use extraConfigmapMounts if available. But that depends from the Chart you are using

Comment: thanks for suggestion @AndD, I needed to copy a json file inside the pod. I have dropped the idea of taking chart from helm-repo, instead cloned it and modified templates for the same. And it's working now.

Comment: That also works for sure, it's just slightly uncomfy because should you want to update your chart, you need to do it manually, but I do that as well when necessary.

Comment: Can you combine the examples from Helm's [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) to create a ConfigMap from the file, and Kubernetes [Add ConfigMap data to a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume) to mount that into the pod?

Comment: Do you use this [grafana](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana) Helm chart ?
You can create `ConfigMap` from your json file and then mount it using `extraConfigmapMounts`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, as i have already checked-in the code, I'll try it very next time.

Comment: @mac_55 any progress ? 
Did you solve your problem?